# IPAD - Image is not selected properly in UIImagePickerController when content size is incresed

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

**EDIT**
I am adding photo. In screenshot I have clicked on cross image right side. But it selects next image. Also see selection gray box.

[image]I have used pop over to show UIImagePickerController. Then changed its contentsize. Now when I click on image 1 second image is selected. Tab positions for all images have shifted.

Here is my code.

```
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cameraUI];
[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(240, 768, 0, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(600, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
cameraUI.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(600, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
```

Also implemented following method, since on click of saved photo, next view in popver was reducing its contentsize.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(600, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
   
}
```

how can I solve this? Please help.

**EDIT**
Also since my default orientation is landscape, my camera view do not rotate in portrait mode. Images are taken in landscape only from camera.

Comment: "Now when I click on image 1 second image is selected." This sentence makes no sense to me - can you rephrase ?

Comment: I have edited question and added a screenshot. Please check.

Comment: Show your bounds as your selected image may help:

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.selectedImageView.bounds inView:self.selectedImageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popOver = popover;